# Motherboard for intel skylake mid-to-high-range gaming pc

Tags: gaming, motherboard

I'm looking into getting a new gaming pc, but I'm not much of a hardware enthusiast. I know what kind of general specs I want to have, but when it comes to details, especially the mainboard, I'm lost with all the kinda same-y, similar price-range motherboards out there.
Here are my current planned specs:

-GTX 1070 (not sure which model yet, but I think that shouldn't matter for this)

-Intel i5 6600K

-2x8GB RAM (Model would depend on mainboard, no?)

-3 Harddrives (2 SSD's, 1HDD) and a Blu Ray Drive

-ATX Chassis

further considerations:
-I'm not likely going to get into overclocking, but I *might* upgrade to SLI at a distant point in the future (if that becomes more viable for gaming in the next years).

-I'm not going to try and desperately squeeze the most bang-for-buck out of this computer, but if you recommend something overly expensive I would need good reasoning to consider it.

-The PC is mostly going to be used for gaming, no fancy hobbies that need special considerations.

**Question:**
What motherboard would you recommend for my set up? Why specifically this one? Are there other considerations I haven't thought of yet?

**Bonus:** What kind of RAM would you get for the motherboard you suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start saying that your setup seems really more-than-good, even of i would go with an Intel Core i7-6700K, and 1 SSD (256GB) and 2 HDD (1TB or + each) cause today's games tent to "eat" many and many Gigs. 
BUT the i5 processors are a really good deal for gaming and you sure did your counts about what you need for the storage parts, those was only advices from my personal point of view.

As per your motherboard choice, i can point you here:

**Asus Z170 Pro Gaming**

It has the latest chipset and it's kinda futureproof 'cause it has the 1151 CPU socket (the i7 mentioned above has the same socket) and it also supports DDR4 Ram (up to 64GB)

There it comes the answer to your "Bonus question";

For the RAM choice, my advice would be:

**Kingston HyperX Fury DDR4 16GB (2x8GB) @ 2666MHz**

I think there's no much to explain here, everything is in the product description.

That's all, hope this helps and if you need any other advice, feel free to ask! :)

Comment: i decided against an i7 because the additional processing power is rarely relevant for video games, and just not worth the steep price increase for me. for the hard drives, i'm going to reuse my two current drives plus a new one i got discounted a while back. i will basically use them like this: 120gb ssd: system, 500gb ssd: "important" games, 2tb hdd: rest. as for the motherboard, that's excactly the one i had my eye on so far, seems i wasn't completely incompetent :) i'll be waiting for additional opinions, though...

Comment: As i said above, you sure did all your consideration about storage and CPU. ;) And yeah, you're right about the processor but i had considered an higher Intel i-CPU to avoid any possibility of bottlenecks, but as far as you will use it mostly for gaming purpose at least you'll get a tiny fps drop here and there that won't really bother you while playing. (And you can still change it in, an eventually, future). Hope the RAM choice is as good as the MoBo one. :)